# ideals of a matrix ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Well my question is the same as this one:[Finding Ideals in $\begin{bmatrix} \mathbb{Q} & \mathbb{Q}\\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1454604/finding-ideals-in-beginbmatrix-mathbbq-mathbbq-0-0-endbmatrix)

I was referred to this link but I still don't understand how to find the left ideals...are they all left ideals principal? If so how would I prove it? Any help will be greatly appreciated. This haunts me for several days :(

Comment: What more than “any subspace is a left ideal (and conversely)” can you expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not all left ideals of this ring are principal. You only need to look at left-multiplication closer, then you will get everything.

$$\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} a_0 & b_0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} aa_0 & ab_0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}=a\begin{bmatrix} a_0 & b_0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

So as an example
$$\langle\begin{bmatrix} a_0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix} 0 & b_0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}\rangle=\{a\begin{bmatrix} a_0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}+b\begin{bmatrix} 0 & b_0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}|a,b\in\mathbb{Q}\}$$
Which can't be generated by one element (also there is only one left-ideal this way and that is equal to the whole ring).
A left-ideal generated by one element like $\begin{bmatrix} a_0 & b_0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ is $\{a\begin{bmatrix} a_0 & b_0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}|a\in\mathbb{Q}\}$.

In fact the left multiplication at above ring is not different than scalar multiplication and ideals get equivalent with subspaces so the left-ideals are nothing except subspaces.

Comment: thank you. it's little confusing to understand left ideals as subspaces of a vector space in a ring problem though.

Comment: @Mathcho In your ring, multiplication from left is like multiplying to entry (1,1) of the left matrix so being closed under multiplying from all elements of your ring from left means being closed under scalar multiplication of all scalars, we have being closed under sum in both ideal and subspace, so now putting these two next to each other, left-ideals and vector sub-spaces are same.

Comment: thank you so much for your kind explaination. i'm sorry if i bother you too much, but is there any method to express left ideals explicitly to compare the left ideals with right ideals to find two sided ideals?

Comment: @Mathcho For representing left-ideals, how do you represent the linear sub-spaces? Is there any form except {0}, the whole space, those generated by one element that you can see its representation above. The right idelas are {0}, the whole ring and only one else you can see at that link on your question. Intersection of these two sets is the right ideals. So right ideals are two-sided ideals too.

Comment: thank you so much i have studied linear algebra years ago so probably need to study stuffs again. i really appreciate your detailed, kind answers.

Comment: i looked up it again...but is really all right ideals left ideals? i don't think so... for example a right ideal whose (1,2) component is in Z and other components zero is never a left ideal.

Comment: @Mathcho what is wrong with $\mathbb{Z}$? Your scalar field is $\mathbb{Q}$ so whether that entry be integer or non-integer rational number, you are multiplying whole rational numbers to it!!!!! And for an arbitrary m/n you only need to use $\frac{m}{na_{1,2}}$. I really don't understand why you think something wants to be wrong with integers!

Comment: Oh sorry if it bothered you too much. but with the right ideal i mentioned above, if we multiplying a matrix whose (1,2) component is 1/2 and others zero with a matrix whose  (1,2) component is 1( so it is in the right ideal i mentioned), the resultant matrix does not belong to the right ideal i mentioned. you said every right ideals are left ideals so i just wondered if it is contradictory to your saying... i'm not trying to drag you down i just asked it out of curiosity......that is math you know.

Comment: @Mathcho Multiplication of those matrices you are saying, from both sides is the zero matrix which belongs to every ideals (right, left, two-sided).

Comment: Oops sorry for the mistake. i actually meant the first matrix to be the matrix whose (1,1) component is 1/2 other components zero

Comment: @Mathcho the linear space generated by your last matrix is only a left-ideal and not a right ideal! I said "two-sided ideals and right ideals are equivalent here", and if you pay attention carefully, set of left ideals of your ring contains right ideals but is strictly bigger.

Comment: oh well comments are maybe too extended. okay  let me think about it by myself. thank you very much for spending your time for me.